# How to override crontab.xml?

Tags: magento2, overrides, configuration, crontab, schedule

I need to override a crontab.xml from:

**vendor/magento/module-integration/etc/crontab.xml**

```
    <job name="expired_tokens_cleanup" instance="Magento\Integration\Cron\CleanExpiredTokens" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
```

To

```
    <job name="expired_tokens_cleanup" instance="Magento\Integration\Cron\CleanExpiredTokens" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/15 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
```

The question is... Which is the best way to do it?

I have already created a file in the path `app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[theme]/Magento_Integration/etc/crontab.xml` but nothing change.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting use a `crontab` file somewhere where you can put your settings in.
If you are using a hosting you should ask them where and how you can adjust it.
**Because the cron is executed server side this is the only way to do that.**

If you want to adjust the settings in the backend how Magento generates cron tasks (this is for generating cron tasks , not executing them) you have 2 options.

**1. Manually**

Adjust them manually under `Stores->Settings->Configuration->Advanced->System`

**2. By module**

Create a module and use a **etc/config.xml** to set the default settings of those fields. Remember that a user can always overwrite them manually.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <cron>
            <template>
                <schedule_generate_every>500</schedule_generate_every>
.....
            </template>
        </cron>
</config>
```

**You can find all available fields under vendor/magento/module-cron/etc/adminhtml/system.xml**

Answer (score 1):

do same entry into core_config_data with same cron expression, it will override that.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an extension having `etc/crontab.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="expired_tokens_cleanup" instance="Magento\Integration\Cron\CleanExpiredTokens" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/15 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a new configuration expression on the DB, above is the query you can use for that

default: it is the group_id of your job
your_job_name: it is the name of your job

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`config_id`, `scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`, `updated_at`) VALUES (NULL, 'default', '0', 
'crontab/default/jobs/your_job_name/schedule/cron_expr', '00 02,12,22 * * *', '2024-01-24 10:02:49');
```